# How do I use "#" in Uri.parse in android programming

Tags: java, android

I am trying to parse a `*123#` in my code but anytime I run the program the `#` never seems to appear:

```
protected void makeCall(){
    Log.i("make call", "");

    Intent phoneIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    phoneIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel: *123#"));

    try{
        startActivity(phoneIntent);
        finish();
        Log.i("finish making call...", "");
    }catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"call failed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Please help me out with this.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void makeCall(){
    Log.i("make call", "");

    Intent phoneIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    phoneIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:*123#"));

    try{
        startActivity(phoneIntent);
       // finish();
        Log.i("finish making call...", "");
    }catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"call failed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Must add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />` in Manifest as well.